# Cayenne Modeler 3.1.2 is using tiny fonts on Windows 3.1.2. Is there a way to fix that?

Tags: apache-cayenne

[It looks like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5JyP.png)

Installed cayenne3.1.2 by downloading the zip and extracting all.
Is there another step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an option to switch your project to 4.0 (which I'd recommend to do regardless), the 4.0 Modeler should look fine on Windows.